# Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1499

Tags: listings

I use this instruction to write algorithme

```
\begin{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
```

And i have this error:

```
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1499. <inserted text> \fi l.1499 if( m.getLatitude()!=-1 && m.getLongtitude()!=-1 && m.getFrecheurL...
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) without more infomation it is impossible for us to help.